# MYSQL Diff From MAX

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to query the MotoGP result
Here's my  [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8a30a/2)

I want to add 2 more columns

1. Pos (1, 2, 3, 4, ...)
2. Gap (rider laptime - 1st pos laptime)

desired result:

- 1 | Marquez | 2799.627 | 2799.627
- 2 | Rossi |2803.143 | 3.516

[image]

my current query:

```
SELECT `rider`, SUM(laptime), COUNT(`lapno`), MAX(`topspeed`) AS ts
FROM
    (SELECT 
    `lapno`,`rider`, (t1+t2+t3+t4) as laptime , `topspeed` 
    FROM `a_lap_time`  as t_laptime) AS a 
GROUP BY a.rider
ORDER BY COUNT(`lapno`) DESC, SUM(laptime) ASC
```

please advise, thank you

Comment: When you say difference lap time, what do you mean?

Comment: sorry from min, in that case 2803.143 - 2799.627

Comment: So Marquez completed in 0 seconds?

Comment: no, marquez 2799.627. top rider showing his laptime, rest of them the difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This result

```
|           rider |  laptime |    Gap | lapno |    ts |
|-----------------|----------|--------|-------|-------|
|    Marc MARQUEZ | 2799.627 |      0 |    30 | 329.3 |
| Valentino ROSSI | 2803.143 |  3.516 |    30 | 319.7 |
```

produced by:

```
SELECT
    `rider`, laptime, laptime - minlaptime as Gap, lapno, ts
FROM (
      SELECT 
          `rider`, laptime, lapno, ts, @lap := IF(@lap = 0.0, laptime, @lap) as minlaptime
      FROM (
            SELECT `rider`, SUM(laptime) as laptime , COUNT(`lapno`) as lapno
                 , MAX(`topspeed`) AS ts
            FROM
                (SELECT 
                `lapno`,`rider`, (t1+t2+t3+t4) as laptime , `topspeed`
                FROM `a_lap_time`  as t_laptime
                 ) AS a 
            GROUP BY a.rider
            ) AS b
      CROSS JOIN (select @lap :=0) var
      ORDER BY `lapno` DESC, laptime ASC 
     ) AS c
```

A variable: **@lap** is "attached" to each row by using a cross join, then using the ORDER BY to get the minimum overall laptime we pass that value into @lap. Once that is done we have the 2799.627 value on each row and we can calculate the Gap.

See this sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bd71f/6

for pos as well:

```
SELECT
    `rider`, laptime, laptime - minlaptime as Gap, lapno, ts, pos
FROM (
      SELECT 
            `rider`, laptime, lapno, ts
           , @lap := IF(@lap = 0.0, laptime, @lap) as minlaptime
           , @pos := @pos + 1 as pos
      FROM (
            SELECT `rider`, SUM(laptime) as laptime , COUNT(`lapno`) as lapno
                 , MAX(`topspeed`) AS ts
            FROM
                (SELECT 
                `lapno`,`rider`, (t1+t2+t3+t4) as laptime , `topspeed`
                FROM `a_lap_time`  as t_laptime
                 ) AS a 
            GROUP BY a.rider
            ) AS b
      CROSS JOIN (select @lap :=0, @pos := 0) var
      ORDER BY `lapno` DESC, laptime ASC 
     ) AS c
```

Result:

```
|           rider |  laptime |   Gap | lapno |    ts | pos |
|-----------------|----------|-------|-------|-------|-----|
|    Marc MARQUEZ | 2799.627 |     0 |    30 | 329.3 |   1 |
| Valentino ROSSI | 2803.143 | 3.516 |    30 | 319.7 |   2 |
```

Comment: hello, thank you for the answer, the gap is correct. but i need to add the Pos column, 1,2,3,4. please help thank you

Comment: "pos" is just a simple integer that increases by one for each row (ordered by laptime). it is another variable

Answer (score 0):

Take your query as it is, just add some [calculations with variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html):

```
SELECT @v_pos := @v_pos + 1 AS pos, rider, sumLaptime, countLaps,
@v_gap := sumLaptime - @v_prev_laptime + @v_gap AS gap,
@v_prev_laptime := sumLaptime AS ignore_me
FROM (
    SELECT `rider`, SUM(laptime) sumLaptime, COUNT(`lapno`) countLaps, MAX(`topspeed`) AS ts
    FROM
        (SELECT 
        `lapno`,`rider`, (t1+t2+t3+t4) as laptime , `topspeed` 
        FROM `a_lap_time`  as t_laptime) AS a 
    GROUP BY a.rider
    ORDER BY COUNT(`lapno`) DESC, SUM(laptime) ASC 
) sq
, (SELECT @v_pos := 0, @v_gap := 0, @v_prev_laptime := 0) var_init_subquery
ORDER BY countLaps DESC, sumLaptime
```

Comment: hey, thank you, the pos is correct, but the gap are return NULL

Comment: Okay, corrected my answer. Please have a try again.

Answer (score -1):

```
CREATe temporary TEMPtable
SELECT `rider`, SUM(laptime) laptimesum, COUNT(`lapno`) lapnocount, MAX(`topspeed`) AS ts
FROM
    (SELECT 
    `lapno`,`rider`, (t1+t2+t3+t4) as laptime , `topspeed` 
    FROM `a_lap_time`  as t_laptime) AS a 
GROUP BY a.rider

SELECT rider,laptimesum,lapnocount,ts,(laptimesum - MAX(laptimesum) AS laptimediff
from TEMPtable
ORDER BY lapnocount DESC, laptimesum asc
```

Sorry for crappy formatting, on mobile.

Comment: not working #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''TEMPtable'' at line 1